# Counting negative, positive and zero element in an array using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array:

```
 var ar1=[];
 var ar=[-1,-2,-3,0,0,5,12,0,-10];
```

I am trying to categorize numbers as "zeros", "negative numbers" and "positive numbers" and counting them.

This is my code:

```
function counter(ar)  { 
   var num,array1=[0,0,0];
   for (i=0;i<ar.length;i++)    {
      switch (ar[i]<0)      {
         case true : array1[0]++;break;
         case false : 
                        if (ar[i]=0) array1[1]++;
                        else array1[2]++;
                        break;
         default : break;
      }
   }
  return(array1);
}
```

Full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function counter(ar)  { 
   var num,array1=[0,0,0];
   for (i=0;i<ar.length;i++)    {
      switch (ar[i]<0)      {
         case true : array1[0]++;break;
         case false : 
                         if (ar[i]=0) array1[1]++;
                        else array1[2]++;
                        break;
         default : break;
      }
   }
  return(array1);
}
</script></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ar1=[];
 var ar=[-1,-2,-3,0,0,5,12,0,-10];
 ar1=counter(ar);
 alert("No of Negative, Zero and Positive Elements are : "+ar1);
</script>
```

The logic seems correct to me, but somehow it's not working. Can someone help me please.

**Update**

I am new in coding and just learning with javascript basics.
I forgot to mention this earlier and now I see hate all over the comments.

**"Is this the best way to do it?"** I should have added this to my question.

I see in comments that switch case is not a good option. So what would be an alternative to that?

Comment: use == `(ar[i]==0)`

Comment: This might help: https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/558ea4f5e39efed371000508

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare you need to use `===`.

`=` is used to assign a value to a variable.

Don't use a `switch` in your case. You only need `if else`

```js
var ar = [-1, -2, -3, 0, 0, 5, 12, 0, -10];

function counter(ar) {
  var counter = [0, 0, 0];
  ar.forEach(function(a) {
    if (a < 0)
      counter[0]++;
    else if (a > 0)
      counter[2]++;
    else
      counter[1]++;
  });
  return counter;
}

var result = counter(ar);
alert("No of Negative, Zero and Positive Elements are : " + result);
```

If you want get all the values separately, one may use object destructuring:

```
 let [negative,zero,positive] = counter([0,0,1,1,2,2]);

 if(! negative) alert("no negative ones but "+zero+" nulls");
```

Comment: @Rajesh I think yes. OP has multiple problems in its code. The comparison but also the use of switch which is bad in this case

Comment: @rajesh yes! Theres no really duplicate for these questions, its a good question for propagating good style ;) [at] OP: ive edited a bit, feel free to rollback...

Comment: @Jonasw Agreed. Even I looked for dupe. I'm not even sure if this falls under typographical mistake as issue is the understanding.

Comment: @Weedoze I have converted arrow function to an anonymous function. Arrow function might confuse OP more. Feel free to rollback the edit if not required

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter method to count with more ease. The following code worked for me.

```
var arr=[-1,-2,-3,0,0,5,12,0,-10]
function myFunction(arr){

   let negatives=arr.filter((el) => el < 0).length;
   let zeros=arr.filter((el) => el == 0).length;
   let positives =arr.filter((el) => el > 0).length;
   return{
       neg:negatives,
       zer:zeros,
       pos:positives
   }
}
console.log(myFunction(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `if (ar[i] == 0) array1[1]++;`.

Answer (score 0):

For counting positive, zero and negative number use below logic, just paste inside console you will get the results.

```js
var ar = [-1, -2, -3, 0, 0, 5, 12, 0, -10];
var zeroCount = 0,
  posCount = 0,
  negativeCount = 0;
ar.forEach((item) => {
  if (item === 0) {
    zeroCount++
  } else if (item < 0) {
    negativeCount++
  } else if (item > 0) {
    posCount++
  }
})

console.log("ZeroCount:: " + zeroCount);
console.log("PositiveCount :: " + posCount);
console.log("NegativeCount:: " + negativeCount);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function myTest(a){

    return a.filter((e) =>(e <0).length)

}

myTest([1,-2,2,-4])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).